# Would a long article using SVG rendered letters (rather than a font) be performant (usable and scrollable)?

Tags: performance, fonts, svg, text, typography

I would like to know if any webpages exist where *every single character/glyph is an SVG path*, rather than using a font.

I look places like [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg-debate/) which discusses icon fonts and how they relate to accessibility and some problems they solve. But I'm wondering if you could do completely without a font like OTF/TTF/WOFF and just instead use SVG paths everywhere.

It looks like you would lose the SEO benefit unless you shadowed your SVG path-driven text content with regular font content beneath the scenes, but either way I would like to know mainly from a *performance* perspective, if it would be technically possible to have a huge long 100 page article and scroll through it quickly at 12-16px font without any flickering or performance issues. That would be an interesting check to see.

Comment: Is there a practical propose, or is it purely curiosity? I haven't heard of a web page like you describe. But my experience is that any sufficiently large SVG or number of images will flicker on scroll in modern browsers.

Comment: It's just a curiosity, I don't like the current font environment.

Comment: What do you dislike about fonts? For my own curiosity.

Comment: I don't understand why it needs to be encapsulated. It makes it hard to customize/animate the glyphs for one. It's a separate workflow from normal vector graphics, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any way to know this without trying it.

Answer (score 2):

Tried it out. Took about ~5 seconds to render 10,000 icons as inline svgs locally, and scrolling flashes white a little bit. Didn't do any optimization, don't really know what could be done, but doesn't seem like a workable solution.